# Different Content showing depending on the domain a visitor arrives on

Tags: channel-entries

A client's site has a main domain ('A'), they also have a parked domain as well ('B'). Depending on the domain that the visitor arrives on the site at, the site would show an older version of some entries, but not others.

Having checked the settings in the control panel, I may have narrowed down that some URLs in the settings had reverted to the parked 'B' domain. This has now been fixed using Deeploy Helper.

My main concern is that the site was showing out of date content which shouldn't have existed. Had anyone ever seen this happen before?

Answer (score 1):

did you try clearing your cache ? ( browser cache and/or cache provided by EE or an add-on like ce cache )

Answer (score 1):

@janvi Myself and client both cleared local caches, and the EE cache.

Turned out issue was related to a recent server move and the IP address and URL hadn't been updated (both in the CMS and in the DNS settings, amazingly) to the correct server when it should have been.